# Validation to check if mandatory fields are filled and if not, print error messages accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my case, there are 3 mandatory fields with 7 entries. If field 1 is filled, it is necessary that field 2 and 3 are to be filled. I want to print an error message if fields 2 and 3 are not filled for the corresponding field 1. However, my code prints the error more than once if not filled for each of field 1, which I don't want.

My piece of code for one entry:

````
        ``` if (Date1 !==""){
            if (Type1 === "") {
            FMStr += "<br/> Type;";
            letter = "false";
            }
            else{
            //do nothing
            }
            if (Purpose1 ==="" ) {
            FMStr += "<br/> Purpose;";
            letter = "false";
            }
            else{
            //do nothing
            }
            }```
````